# Which node.js version to install in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, webrtc, node-gyp

I am trying to install [Truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle) in my Ubuntu 16.10 system.
Before that I need to install node.js. The latest v8 is not supported. So I downloaded v7 and installed its `build-essential` tools. But while installing Truffle (`sudo npm install -g truffle`) I find an error saying:

> node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404):
>   https://node-webrtc.s3.amazonaws.com/wrtc/v0.0.61/Release/node-v51-linux-ia32.tar.gz
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for wrtc@0.0.61 and
>   node@7.10.0 (node-v51 ABI) (falling back to source compile with
>   node-gyp)

And then, a moment later, this error pops up:

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
>   (node_modules/truffle/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"})
>
> npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-59-generic 
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "truffle" 
>   npm ERR! node v7.10.0 
>   npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0 
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! wrtc@0.0.61 install: `node-pre-gyp install
>   --fallback-to-build` npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!  Failed at the wrtc@0.0.61 install script 'node-pre-gyp
>   install --fallback-to-build'. Make sure you have the latest version of
>   node.js and npm installed. If you do, this is most likely a problem
>   with the wrtc package, not with npm itself. Tell the author that this
>   fails on your system:     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

Which version is supported by Yakkety? Should I revert to a previous version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to install

```
sudo npm install node-pre-gyp -g
```

After this

```
sudo npm install -g truffle
```

If you still have problems, such as C compiler installed
g++ && gcc for ubuntu

Comment: Obviously OP already installed node-pre-gyp. from error message `node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for wrtc@0.0.61`

Comment: I have installed node-gyp, prebuild as well as node-pre-gyp.